# Use multiple screens on the single tab

Tags: react-native, tabs, screen, react-native-tabnavigator

Hello I am using this code in the react native for creating tabs. but i want to use multiple screens on the single according to the user pressed buttons. so how can i do this in react native

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(  
    {  
      Home:{  
        screen:Screen1,  
        navigationOptions:{  
          tabBarLabel:'firsttab',  
          tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
              <Image source = {require("../../Images/react-logo.png")} style={{width : 25 , height:25}}/> 
          )  
        }  
      },
```

i am getting screen1 but i want that on click firsttab i want to switch tab screens. how can i do this.

Comment: What do u mean of "on click firat tab i want to switch tab screen"?

Answer (score 1):

It's something like you have to create a stackNavigator and use it in the bbottomTabNavigator . see the below code :

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    HomeScreen: {
      screen: Home
    },
    AirportMeeting:{
      screen:AirportMeeting
    },
    MeetingPoint:{
      screen:MeetingPoint
    },
    DriverDetails:{
      screen:DriverDetails
    },
    },
  {

    initialRouteName:"HomeCard",

  }
);
```

and now in your bottomtab navigator , you just include AppStack and other screens ,

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: AppStack,
  Notification:Notifications,
  Account: SettingsScreen,

});
```

here Home has appstack and app stack has multiple screens inside it. Im using `react-navigation` for it .  check the link [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html) . .

and also im using  createStackNavigator and createBottomTabNavigator , check in there docs.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts/

Answer (score 0):

```
const Screen1 = createStackNavigator({
  //...path your screen1,
});

const Screen2 = createStackNavigator({
  //...path your screen2,
});

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Screen1,
  Screen2
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't post code only answers, it would be nice to explain your code aswell.

Comment: how to set condition on it. so if i click on the tab which screen have to be load.

Comment: i want to show two screens on a single tab. if condition will true then first screen load to tab otherwise second screen load to tabs